# Validation error with ArrayList

Tags: java, validation, exception, arraylist

I'm attempting to add an ArrayList to an object with a do...while loop. Unfortunately I continue to get a validation error each time I run the program.

Here is the function that I am using to add an ArrayList to the object DVD:

```
    public DVD getNewDVDInfo() {

    String title = io.readString("Please enter DVD title");
    String releaseDate = io.readString("Please enter Release Date (mm-DD-yyyy)");
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(releaseDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("mm-DD-yyyy"));
    String mpaaRating = io.readString("Please enter MPAA Rating");
    String directorName = io.readString("Please enter Director's Name");
    String studio = io.readString("Please enter Studio");
    boolean hasNext = true;
    ArrayList<String> userRating = new ArrayList<>();
    String userRatingString = io.readString("Please enter User Rating");

    userRating.add(userRatingString);
    DVD currentDVD = new DVD(title);
    currentDVD.setReleaseDate(ld);
    currentDVD.setMpaaRating(mpaaRating);
    currentDVD.setDirectorName(directorName);
    currentDVD.setStudio(studio);
    currentDVD.setUserRating(userRating);

    return currentDVD;
}
```

The validation method:

```
    private void validateDVDData(DVD dvd) throws DVDLibraryDataValidationException {
    if (dvd.getTitle() == null || dvd.getTitle().trim().length() == 0
            || dvd.getReleaseDate() == null
            || dvd.getMpaaRating() == null || dvd.getMpaaRating().trim().length() == 0
            || dvd.getDirectorName() == null || dvd.getDirectorName().trim().length() == 0
            || dvd.getStudio() == null || dvd.getStudio().trim().length() == 0
            || dvd.getUserRating()== null || dvd.getUserRating().isEmpty()); {

        throw new DVDLibraryDataValidationException("ERROR: All fields [Title, Release Date, MPAA Rating, Director's Name, Studio, User Rating] are required");
    }
}
```

Every time I run the app, the error message is thrown. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Answer (score 0):

To identify your problem you could use a debugger but you could also improve the way of doing the check.

Instead of doing a global error :

> ERROR: All fields [Title, Release Date, MPAA Rating, Director's Name,
>   Studio, User Rating] are required");

it would be more helpful to the user (and also to you for tracing the information) to know where is exactly the problem in the provided values.

In your `DVDLibraryDataValidationException` class, you could add a List of `String` field where you add the error field names.
And you could override `getMessage()` of this class to provide a helpful message indicating the fields with validation error.

Just to give an idea on the way to start :

```
List<String> errorFields = new ArrayList<>();
 if (dvd.getTitle() == null || dvd.getTitle().trim().length() == 0){
    errorFields.add("title");
 }

 if (dvd.getReleaseDate() == null ){
    errorFields.add("release date");
 }
 ...
 if (!errorFields.isEmpty()){
    throw new DVDLibraryDataValidationException("ERROR: All fields [Title, Release Date, MPAA Rating, Director's Name, Studio, User Rating] are required", 
                                                 errorFields);
 }
```